# checkbox OnCheckChange gets called twice by pressing Spinner

Tags: java, android

the problem with this is that the listener OnCheckChangeListener is called twice... and this triggers the problem see below.

```
public class HomeFragmentActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity {
 ...
 @Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    switch(item.getItemId()){
    case R.id.id_logout: removeSavedCustomer(this);
            Intent i = new Intent(this , SplashActivity.class);
            i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            i.putExtra("activity_change", 0 );
            startActivity(i);
        break;
    case R.id.id_compose: 

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        ViewGroup view = (ViewGroup) LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.new_message, null);

        Spinner select = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.messaging_spinner);

        /**
         *  add spinner adapter and list
         */
        ProjectHelper helper = new ProjectHelper(this);
        final List<MessageProject> m_project = getSpinnerData(this , helper.getListAsMessage());
        // add a dummy
        m_project.add( 0 , new MessageProject());

        final SpinnerAdapter adapter = new SpinnerAdapter(this , m_project);

        select.setAdapter(adapter);

        final EditText m_title = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.messaging_title);
        final EditText m_content = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.messaging_content);

        final TextView err_spinner = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.err_message_spinner);
        final TextView err_title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.err_message_title);
        final TextView err_content = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.err_message_content);

        err_spinner.setTextColor(Color.RED);
        err_title.setTextColor(Color.RED);
        err_content.setTextColor(Color.RED);



        m_title.addTextChangedListener(new AfterTextChanged(){

            @Override
            public void abstract_afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if(!isValidString(s.toString())){
                    error = true;
                    err_title.setText("Title should not be empty");
                }else{
                    error = false;
                    err_title.setText("");
                }


            }

        });

        m_content.addTextChangedListener(new AfterTextChanged(){

            @Override
            public void abstract_afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if(!isValidString(s.toString())){
                    error = true;
                    err_content.setText("Content should not be empty");
                }else{
                    error = false;
                    err_content.setText("");
                }
            }

        });


        Button message = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.m_btn_message);
        Button cancel = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.m_btn_cancel);

        builder.setView(view);

        final AlertDialog alert = builder.create();

        message.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                /**
                 *  messaging action
                 */
            }

        });

        cancel.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                alert.dismiss();
            }

        });
        alert.show();
        break;


    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}





public class SpinnerAdapter extends AbstractListAdapter<MessageProject> implements  IImageDownload {

protected static final String TAG = "SpinnerAdapter";
private LayoutInflater inflater;

public SpinnerAdapter(Context context, List<MessageProject> lists) {
    super(context, lists);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
}

@Override
public View getOverridedView(int position, View child, ViewGroup root) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ViewHolder holder = null;
    final MessageProject mprojects = getList().get(position);
    if(child == null){
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        child = inflater.inflate(R.layout.message_spinner_projects, null , false);
        holder.image = (ImageView) child.findViewById(R.id.mp_image);
        holder.name = (TextView) child.findViewById(R.id.mp_project_name);
        holder.checkBox = (CheckBox) child.findViewById(R.id.mp_cbox);

        child.setTag(holder);
    }else{
        holder = (ViewHolder) child.getTag();
    }

    if(position == 0){
        holder.name.setText("Select atleast 1");
        holder.checkBox.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        holder.image.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        holder.checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null);

    }else{
        holder.checkBox.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        holder.image.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        holder.name.setText(mprojects.getName());
        holder.checkBox.setChecked(mprojects.isCheck());

        holder.checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener(){

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton arg0, boolean arg1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Log.d(TAG, arg0.toString());
                Log.v(TAG, "FROM " + mprojects.isCheck() + " TO " + arg1 );
                mprojects.setCheck(arg1);
                Log.d(TAG, "Project " + mprojects.getId());
                saveSpinnerData(inflater.getContext() , mprojects);
            }

        });

        /*
         *  download the weak reference bitmap image for imageview
         */
        // remove this when online
        String replace = mprojects.getImagePath().replace("http://localhost/", Utilities.HOST_NAME);
        //
        mprojects.setImagePath(replace);
        download(mprojects.getImagePath() , holder.image);
    }



    return child;
}


@Override
public void download(String url, ImageView view) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    BitmapDownloaderTask task = new BitmapDownloaderTask(view);
    task.execute(url);

}

private class ViewHolder {
    ImageView image;
    TextView name;
    CheckBox checkBox;
}
}
/**
 *  get the spinner selected projects if there is
 */
public static List<MessageProject> getSpinnerData(Context context  , List<MessageProject> data){
    SharedPreferences shared = getPreferences(context);
    for(MessageProject mproject: data){

        Log.d(TAG, "PROEJCT " + mproject.getId() + " = " + shared.getBoolean("message_is_checked_" + mproject.getId(), false));
        mproject.setCheck(shared.getBoolean("message_is_checked_" + mproject.getId(), false));

    }

    return data;

}
/**
 *  save the spinner selected projects
 */
public static void saveSpinnerData(Context context, MessageProject data){
    SharedPreferences shared = getPreferences(context);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = shared.edit();

    if(shared.getLong("project_id_" + data.getId(), -1) != -1){
        editor.putBoolean("message_is_checked_"+data.getId() ,data.isCheck() );
    }else{
        editor.putLong("project_id_" + data.getId(), data.getId());
    }
    editor.commit();
}
```

[image: http://i.imgur.com/ZorRWT0.png?2]

"here is the image of the spinner and the checkbox there is my problem when i pressed back , and when i pressed again spinner it gets called twice now the data will be false even though it is checked, because the setOnCheckChangeListener onCheckChanged gets called not just once but twice. how is this happening?... what is the possible solution?"

*im so out of solution right now. so bad.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!  **removed onCheckChangedListener** change to **onClickListener**
Because setCheck fires OnCheckChangedListener, stupid me

```
            holder.checkBox.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Log.d(TAG, arg0.toString());
                Log.v(TAG, "FROM " + mprojects.isCheck() + " TO " + !mprojects.isCheck() );
                mprojects.setCheck(!mprojects.isCheck());
                Log.d(TAG, "Project " + mprojects.getId());
                saveSpinnerData(inflater.getContext() , mprojects);
            }


        });
```

*still any answer is much appreciated, because i want to use oncheckchangelistener badly*

**its just weird , cause im pressing the spinner not the checkbox , still oncheckchanged listener fires off**